# How do I convert a field to the primary key and consolidate the duplicates into one record?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm a newbie to Access and I'm trying to create a database for the internals of a gas turbine by part. Right now, I'm just trying to enter all the raw data we have as best I can, but eventually, I would like each unique "part number" to be its own record. However, sometimes the same part is used in different stages of the machine, and the raw data is arranged by the usage of the part, not by the part number. The raw data also has no primary key. I would like each part number, along with ALL of that unique part's uses, to be in one record. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: I think I would use 2 tables - a part number master file with all the common data for each part, and a second table of the assemblies that use the parts - like a BOM file.  The part number would be a the primary key in the 1st file, but not the 2nd.  If you try to put all the assemblies in the part number record, you will have trouble re-normalizing the data later.

Comment: This question is very broad. Start by asking yourself: how do I consolidate my duplicates into one row. Once you have a query doing that, you can add a primary key. But consolidating varies on your actual data.

Comment: @DonGeorge Thats most likely what I will end up doing. Im just not sure the best way to go about consolidating multiple entries into one field

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I guess thats what I am struggling with. Is there a way to have a field link to another table with the multiple entries associated with that one part number?

Comment: @RBuntu Yes, of course. You're still a bit vague though, so I can't tell you how exactly.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Ok, how about if I can consolidate multiple entries of the same part number into one field of Comma separated values on one record? Is there a tutorial on that?

Comment: @erikvonAsmuth For example, if I have 3 records, Part numbers A, B, and B, and I plan to make the part number the primary key, is there a way to make it so that both the records with B as the part number combine into one record with their values making up a list of comma separated values?

Comment: That's a bad idea in my opinion. A better one would be to have a separate table listing all possible part numbers once (possibly as primary key), and just having 2 rows for a certain part number (or even just using a `SELECT DISTINCT PartNumber` if you want all part numbers once). You can read in on "multi-valued fields in Access" (Google), but you mostly will find people complaining about how awful that is.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth But if my part number is my primary key, how can I have 2 rows for a certain part number? Just trying to wrap my head around how Access works. I read up on multivalued fields in Access and it seems to fit some of my needs for another field that can have the values "A,B,C,D or E" or any combination of those values.

Comment: As said, separate table including only part numbers, separate table including duplicates with another primary key